# Recursively load all sub categories

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to preload all categories subcategories.

Example:

```
-> Sport
    -> Football
        -> Man
        -> Woman
    -> Handbal
        -> Man
        -> Woman
```

So far I managed to preload only first child here is the code I am using:

```
schema "categories" do
    has_many :subCategories, Category, foreign_key: :parent_id

    ------

    Repo.all from category in Category,
        left_join: subCategories in assoc(category, :subCategories),
        preload: [subCategories: subCategories],
        where: is_nil(category.parent_id)
```

I found a way how to load all children categories but it makes too much SQL queries (http://tensiondriven.github.io/posts/recursively-load-self-referential-association-using-ecto)

Answer (score 1):

This is how i have used to preload the categories and subcategories.
Hope that helps

`Repo.preload([:category1, :category2, 
         category3: [subcategory1: [subcat1: :subcat2]]])`

However i would recommend to use joins in SQL, because preload takes seperate database trips for each association. Joins would do that in just one db trip.

Comment: This is okay answer if you know how many subcategories you have, I ended up loading all subcategories and sorting them in the tree with loops in elixir